# How do I force the WordPress post thumbnail to display at a fixed size?

Tags: wordpress

I want the post thumbnail image to display at a fixed size (large), no matter what. If the full size image is bigger, use the large one (and do not downscale the full one). If the full size image is smaller, use the full size, set width/height attributes of the img element and let the browser do the up-scaling. Been playing with `get_the_post_thumbnail` and conditionals for a while, but fail to get width/height attributes right without getting messy.

Anyone willing to share a clean solution?

Comment: Simply Use CSS to fixed height weight

Comment: It's not that simple. See my comment at marcin.gs answer.

Comment: Check my answer and find Post "Thumbnail Linking to Large Image Size" change the `large` with `full`

Answer (score 5):

Re-check your theme support `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');`

**Default WordPress Thumbnail**

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );     // Thumbnail (150 x 150 hard cropped)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );        // Medium resolution (300 x 300 max height 300px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium_large' );  // Medium Large (added in WP 4.4) resolution (768 x 0 infinite height)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );         // Large resolution (1024 x 1024 max height 1024px)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );          // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

**If You need a specific resolutions**

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(500, 500) );  // 500x500 dimension
```

**Post Thumbnail Linking to Large Image Size** you can change the size by changing `large`

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
    if ( ! empty( $large_image_url[0] ) ) {
        printf( '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            esc_url( $large_image_url[0] ),
            esc_attr( get_the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ),
            get_the_post_thumbnail()
        );
    }
}
```

**You can also create custom featured image sizes in your theme’s functions**

```
 add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 300, 300); //Simple widget size
 add_image_size( 'sidebar-thumb', 120, 120, true ); // Hard Crop Mode
 add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180 ); // Soft Crop Mode
 add_image_size( 'singlepost-thumb', 590, 9999 ); // Unlimited Height Mode
```

**Here is an example of how to create custom Featured Image sizes in your theme’s `functions.php` file.**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 300, 300); // 300 pixels wide 
 }
```

**Displaying additional image sizes in your WordPress theme**

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'your-specified-image-size' ); //Example singlepost-thumb
```

Comment: The main issue is up scaling in the browser. I can't get a full image which is  smaller (!) than the large one to scale up and appear at large dimensions. Don't see how your answer addresses that.

Comment: post thumbnail use the large image i have added the code above please check

Comment: If the full image is smaller than large dimensions demand, the img tag will always have width/height set to the (small) values of the full image. Problem is $hwstring in wp_get_attachment_image which is called by get_the_post_thumbnail. Seems there is no clean fix. The best I could come up with was calling get_the_post_thumbnail and replacing the values in the string returned.

Answer (score 0):

I will try this solution:

1) add to `functions.php` this: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

2) then in `wordpress loop` add this: `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'full'); ?>`

Comment: It's not that simple. Assume the full image is way bigger than the large one. One surely does not want it to appear in the src attribute of the image tag. Will explicitly add that requirement to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It is horrible, but I found no other half decent way to get around the `$hwstring` issue in `wp_get_attachment_image`.

```php
$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
$lw = get_option( "large_size_w");
// Scale up if full version size is smaller than large
if ($image_data[1] < intval($lw)) {
    $ratio = $lw / $image_data[1];
    $h = round($ratio * $image_data[2]);
    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'full', array(title => get_the_title()));
    $thumb = preg_replace('#\s(width)="[^"]+"#', ' width="'.$lw.'"', $thumb);
    echo preg_replace('#\s(height)="[^"]+"#', ' height="'.$h.'"', $thumb);
} else {
    the_post_thumbnail('large', array(title => get_the_title() ) );
}
```